# Как сделать правильный относительный импорт в Python?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Имеется проект, со структурой, представленной на скриншоте ниже. Не могу разобраться как сделать правильный относительный импорт из внешней директории. Так, как сделано сейчас у меня работает, НО, PyCharm указывает на ошибку, и не могу протестировать функции, которые находятся в этом файле, т.к. он не запускается, указывая на ошибку. Если я запускаю сервер, то это работает, как и импорт. У меня вопрос как сделать этот импорт правильным, и не будет проблем потом при deploy

[image: картинка структура проекта]

Comment: в импорте укажите корневую директорию: `from root.additional.models import ...` ps и пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1295795/edit))

Comment: @Jack_oS, ок, учту, просто не знал как показать это вместе с иерархией папок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделать директорию над "additional" - "Sources root":

- правой кнопкой мыши на директорию;
- Mark Directory as;
- Sources Root.

Comment: [пример](https://imgur.com/a/oyRNx7H)